# Java: MySQL connection won't close

Tags: java, mysql

I can't close a connection I'm getting using `DriverManager.getConnection` (package `java.sql`). The query is successful, but the `close()` hangs, showing these errors after some time:

```
Counted: 19020 rsvps.
About to close connection
[WARNING] thread Thread[Abandoned connection cleanup thread,5,recmeet.tester.RecmeetSqlTester] was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least 15000msecs
[WARNING] thread Thread[Abandoned connection cleanup thread,5,recmeet.tester.RecmeetSqlTester] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] NOTE: 1 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to  via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
[WARNING] Couldn't destroy threadgroup org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=recmeet.tester.RecmeetSqlTester,maxpri=10]
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
```

This is the code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/recmeet", "alexis","password");
Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from rsvp;");
rs.next();
int resultInt = rs.getInt(1);
System.out.println("Counted: " + resultInt + " rsvps.");
rs.close();
stmt.close();
if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
    System.out.println("About to close connection");
    try {
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("SQL exception: " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

The database is a MySQL 5.7.17, `my-sql-connector` version 6.0.5, on a commodity Fedora Linux box.

Comment: I would change log level to DEBUG first to see what's going on there.

Comment: Can you try to set conn null right after conn.close()?

Comment: The error doesn't complain about not closed connections (although they should be closed in a finally block). It complains about a thread that is being interrupted, but doesn't honor the interruption and keeps running. What does your RecmeetSqlTester class do?

Comment: I am not sure the problem is related to the close() call. It is maybe caused as soon as the class has terminated its execution. According to logs, you use exec-maven-plugin. Is `cleanupDaemonThreads` is enabled ? Default value is: true. `<cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>` should be added in the plugin configuration to disable it. It will maybe not solve your root problem but it could give some pointers.

Comment: @davidxxx : you're right, `close()` returns, and disabling `cleanupDaemonThreads` leads to the program terminating normally. Any idea what this means?

Comment: I think you have a thread related to MySql JDBC connector usage that is never released  even after an interruption request.  `Abandoned connection cleanup thread` is the name of the Thread.  In fact when you disable `cleanupDaemonThread`, the exec-maven-plugin doesn't try to do the clean up daemon threads related to its execution. You can maybe try a more recent mysql connector. You have information here too : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69526

Comment: Or maybe your MySQL server version and your MySQL connector are not fully compatible between them. You could also check it.